# python openpyxl find certain cell then return the next nonempty cell

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to work with this excel sheet. Once i find the cell that contains "Mandatory Field", I want to keep looking down that column to find the first nonempty value.

```
 for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row[0:4]:
            if cell.value == 'Mandatory Field'
                print (cell.value)
```

This is what I have so far. I do not know how to tell it to say ok now that you have found the cell with Mandatory field. return the the value of the cell that is not empty below you. I am looking through 5 columns because i need to do this to twice.

Comment: Do you not know how to search through cells, or how to tell if a cell is empty or not?  And what does the "need to do this twice" have to do with scanning 5 columns?

Comment: i guess both to the first question. my if statement should work for that specific string no? but then i dont know how to tell it to keep looking for another nonempty value because the file could have blank cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this twice within a range of cells you should use a "sentinel" flag.

```
sentinel = False
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_col=5):
    for cell in row:
         if cell.value == "Mandatory Field":
              sentinel = True
         if sentinel = True:
              print(cell.offset(row=1).value)
              sentinel = False
```

Note that in the example you can avoid the use of a sentinel because of the `offset()` method but I'm including it as an example.